# Unload dll files from a MFC Program

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, mfc

I have a MFC program that even I close the program it does not get away and still shown in the task manager. When I look at the call stack I saw that some dll files are only loaded but not unloaded.

Is thee a way to make all the dll files unloaded when exit the program? So the exe will not be shown in the task manager.

I have declared  some variables at top of the class:

```
vtkPoints *newPts = vtkPoints::New();
vtkPoints *newPtsSuction  = vtkPoints::New();     
CArray <double,double> ScalarValues_pressure;
CArray <double,double> ScalarValues_suction;
CArray <double,double> ScalarValues;
```

And add the values to them in another function and use the variables directly in another function.

Comment: DLLs are automatically unloaded by the operating system when your application closes. You're trying to solve this problem the wrong way round. The real issue is something in your application's code that is preventing it from closing. Impossible to say what it is without seeing the code. Consider updating your question.

Comment: Thanks Cody Gray. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in first place is not DLL unloading. Your application freezes in a sort of dead loop or otherwise does not complete the termination properly. Having this fixed, the libraries will be unloaded automatically and the process will go, including from the task list.

Comment: Thread stacks - check what your application is doing and why it does not destroy everything in response to closing request. You might also want to put a break point into `WM_CLOSE` and `WM_DESTROY` message  handlers (such as `OnClose`, `OnDestroy` in your top level window) and step through code from there to see where it possibly gets stuck.